# How to track all changes inside a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to know whether there is any api ***to get all changes inside a sharepoint site***. I've done research in sharepoint and found out that changes api retrieves changes inside a list. I would like to get relative urls or unique id's of files changed ***inside a sharepoint site*** with or without supplying a change token. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked out 'auditing'? It's an OOTB way to track changes on files, lists, librarys etc...

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012

Otherwise i would suggest to write event receivers and store the changes yourself in a database table for performance.

Comment: Don't know if there is an API but auditing in SharePoint is something out of the box so no coding needed. It will register a whole bunch of events and you can check those audit logs as needed

Comment: Apparantly there is a SPAudit class available. I think it's possible to code extra audit log entries when something is not there out of the box
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaudit.aspx